# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mailmerge' python

Tags: python-3.x

from mailmerge import MailMerge

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mailmerge'

Pease help on this

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.org/project/docx-mailmerge/#files

Do you have mailmerge installed? There aren't many details you're giving us here.

Try `pip install docx-mailmerge`

Otherwise download the .whl file in the link provided and place it in the correct path.

Then you can do `pip install [location of file].whl`

Unless you supply more info, that's all I can tell you.

Comment: Hi ,Thank you for your reply. I have installed this package pip install docx-mailmerge.When I try to import the from mailmerge import MailMerge when try to execute the python program ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mailmerge' error getting

Comment: You didn't really give us any more information... What version of Python are you running? What IDE are you using? You could always take this to the Official Python Discord. https://discord.gg/python  They are very helpful, and you can send pictures, code snippets, etc. I can't help you with the information you are giving me.

Comment: I am using Python 3.8.1 and the IDE i am using VSCODE

Comment: You should try to see what version pip is on with `pip --version` and make sure it is using python 3.8.1. I just tried installing it and running it on anaconda and it imported just fine. I would go to the discord link I provided and ask there. Also, the module might not be updated to 3.8.1. Make sure it uses 3.8.1. The last commit to the module was in October so I doubt it is updated. You might have to use a lower version of python. I used 3.7.

Comment: Yes docx-mailMerge uses   pip show docx-mailmerge
Name: docx-mailmerge
Version: 0.5.0
Summary: Performs a Mail Merge on docx (Microsoft Office Word) files
Home-page: http://github.com/Bouke/docx-mailmerge
Author: Bouke Haarsma
Author-email: bouke@webatoom.nl
License: MIT
Location: /Users/b154825/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: lxml
Required-by:

Answer (score 0):

Although it has been a while
for me was the solution to uninstall the module "mailmerge"
and after that it worked.